# Copying blob column contents from one table to another in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm currently trying to copy the contents of a blob column from one table to another in Oracle Apex 5 and no matter what, it doesn't copy the BLOB data over, it leaves all those fields blank and it's driving my nuts.

Here is the PL/SQL I'm using to accomplish this as a process.

```
insert into ATTACHMENTS_AVAIL 
  ("ADDED_FILE", "MIMETYPE", "FILENAME", "CONTRACTOR_ID", "DATE_ADDED", "TYPE") 
select RESUME,
       MIMETYPE,
       FILENAME,
       :P24_CONTRACTOR_ID,
       sysdate,
       'Resume'
from subs 
where pkey = :P24_SUBS_PKEY;
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Here are the field types.

```
ADDED_FILE    - BLOB
MIMETYPE      - VARCHAR2
FILENAME      - VARCHAR2
CONTRACTOR_ID - NUMBER
DATE_ADDED    - DATE
TYPE          - VARCHAR2
```

Comment: More details to the question... we have no idea what the table definitions are, what the column datatypes are, what "those fields" are?

Comment: APEX 5 is irrelevant to this question - what happens when you try this in SQL Developer, Toad etc.?

Comment: APEX is actually pretty relevant since I can do this from a SQL Commands window easily, it's when I try to accomplish it as a process in an APEX 5 form that it goes south.

Comment: Updated the post to include column data types.

Comment: Can you explain more what the difference are b/w executing in SQL Commands and in a page in Apex?

Answer (score 0):

> (...) it leaves all those fields blank

It means that `WHERE` clause failed, completely:

- either there's no `SUBS.PKEY` whose value is equal to `P24_SUBS_PKEY` item value, or
- `P24_SUBS_PKEY` is *empty*

How come? Because, even if every other value was NULL, `SYSDATE` (you insert into `DATE_ADDED`) and 'Resume' (which goes into `TYPE` column) would be inserted. So, `INSERT` failed because `SELECT` failed because `WHERE` doesn't work.

I presume you checked whether `SUBS` table contains appropriate values. Therefore, I presume that `P24_SUBS_PKEY` item doesn't contain anything. Perhaps you *see* the value on the screen, but - is it in session state? I guess not. Enable debugging and check the sessions state values after the process ends.

Saying that you wrote a *process* which should do the `INSERT` - when does that process "fire"? The simplest way is, probably, when you push a button which submits the page. And, once you submit it, items' values are "stored" into session state. I suggest you to do that, just to make sure it actually works. Then you can *improve* the whole thing, if necessary.